# Publishing image classifier as a website or to the cloud

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, wolfram-cloud

I have made an image classifier by importing images and training my neural network, and I would like to share this classifier with my colleagues that don't have access to Mathematica.
However, if I just publish my notebook using *Publish to Cloud*, it does not allow them to add their own images to the classifier.

How can I share or publish my classifier so that people without Mathematica can use it?

Comment: Maybe you could export the network in the [ONNX format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/ONNX.html)?

Comment: @flinty cheers just found this post about it https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/01/07/deploy-a-neural-network-to-your-ios-device-using-the-wolfram-language/